# Swift IF Statement Issue - Unary operator Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Have an error with the swift below code, I assume I can't use comparison operator within a 'if' statement...?

I receive the error

> 'Unary operator cannot be seperated from its operand' if i try to use
>   an && or || on after the first 'else' statement.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if (row < 8)
        {
            self.pickerLabel.text = "Too cold";

        }
        else if(row >= 8 && <= 10) // Error occurs here...
        {
            self.pickerLabel.text = "Just right";
        }
        else if(row == 12)
        {
            self.pickerLabel.text = "Too warm";
        }
        else
        {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        }
    }
```

Is there a work around, or solution that will get me around the error that anyone knows of?

Thanks.

Comment: else if (row >= 8 && row <= 10)  pass this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You're close.

The line should read:

```
else if row >= 8 && row <= 10 // No more error
```

(Note that you don't need parentheses around the if expression either)

With order of operations the inequalities are evaluated before the logical "AND" (&&). As Martin pointed out in his comments, logical "AND" and the other logical operators are "short circuit" operators in Swift like they are in C.

If the expression on the left of a logical AND is false, the next part of the expression isn't evaluated at all since you can be sure that the entire expression will be false.

## Edit:

This would be a good situation to use the swift case statement, since it allows ranges in cases.

## Edit #2:

You are missing handling for row = 11.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, had been staring at it for so long that I didn't see it!

Comment: Minor remark: *"Both inequalities are evaluated first, ..."* is not entirely true because `&&` is a "short-circuiting" operator. If the lhs yields false then the rhs is not evaluated.

Comment: Good point Martin. Thanks for correcting my sloppy statement.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `<=` without an explicit reference on the left side. As you've been told, the simple way is:

```
if row >= 8 && row <= 10
```

However, the Swift idiom for testing "betweenness" is:

```
if (8...10).contains(row)
```

Even more idiomatic, you should be using a switch statement:

```
switch row {
case 0..<8: //...
case 8...10: //...
case 12: //...
default: //...
}
```

By the way, you have left out 11 (perhaps intentionally).

Comment: In the switch statement, why do you use "0..<8" instead of "0...7"? What is the difference? Is there an advantage to that?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
else if row >= 8 && row <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest that you always use parenthesis in cases like this for additional clarity.

```
else if (row >= 8) && (row <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    if (row < 8)
    {
        self.pickerLabel.text = "Too cold";

    }
    else if(row >= 8 && row <= 10) // Error occurs here...
    {
        self.pickerLabel.text = "Just right";
    }
    else if(row == 12)
    {
        self.pickerLabel.text = "Too warm";
    }
    else
    {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }
}
```